# Media Queries for Images Slideshow with List Items

Tags: html, css, list, media-queries, slideshow

I have a background slideshow that is created with the  tag.

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>3</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>5</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>6</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>7</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It has seven images that fade and transition after a certain interval. However I havent been able to find out any way to get them to resize when I insert them into a media query. How do i resize them when I use a width of lets say 480 px?

Here is my CSS for the slideshow.

```css
.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(2.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(3.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(4.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-image: url(5.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  background-image: url(6.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(7) span {
  background-image: url(7.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I'm trying to get the entire slideshow, consisting of the images to retain the transition functionality when I open it in a mobile browser however resize as and when required.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The parts of the CSS that you gave us work well with different screen sizes even without media queries. I think the part that does not work well with it is probably the `imageAnimation` but we can't help you with that as long as you don't post it.